# what is the value of SESSIONID in this class?

Tags: java, sessionid

In a project I'm working on, I see this snippet of code:

```
 @Autowired
    private ContextBuilder contextBuilder;     
response = service.payment(contextBuilder.getContext(), request);
```

request and response are two beans which contain input and output requests. 
And class Contextbuilder is like this:

```
 private Context context;
    private ContextEntry contextEntry;
    private UserInfoRequestBean userInfo;
    private String sessionId;
    private boolean session = false;

    public ContextBuilder() {
        this.context = new Context();
        this.contextEntry = new ContextEntry();
    }

     public Context getContext() {
            this.contextEntry.setKey("SESSIONID");
            this.contextEntry.setValue(sessionId( null));
            this.context.getData().add(this.contextEntry);
            return this.context;
        }

        public String sessionId(String sessionId) {
            if (this.session) {
                this.session = false;
                synchronized (ContextBuilder.class) {
                    if (sessionId != null) {
                        this.sessionId = sessionId;
                        return null;
                    } else {
                        return this.sessionId;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                return this.sessionId;
            }
        }
```

I can't get what is getContext() and especially sessionId() doing? what is it putting for SESSIONID's value? is it putting always null? if yes why?

Comment: It looks like a walking talking bug to me. Why should `sesssion` become false just because you assign a new session ID? and where are the comments that should state what's happening here? I would treat this code with extreme suspicion.

Comment: unfortunately there is no comment and that's why I can't make head or tail of it. @EJP